# RegEx for ignoring certain words

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation, regex-group

What is a regex for ignoring words in a given sentence?

Input:
`Online Mobile Order is not working`

Output:
`Online Mobile Order`

I'm trying to get some automation tool to flag cases where the combination Online Mobile Order appears.

In my current case I use it as follows:
(Online Mobile Order|Mobile Online Order|Online Order Mobile)

This allows to flag these combinations regardless of their ordering.

But, sometimes I need to capture "Online Mobile Order is not working" but the addition of "is not working" will not flag this sentence for me.

I was looking for similar answers here but since I'm not across Regex, I wasn't sure if any answer was matching my problem.

Comment: *but the addition of "is not working" will not flag this sentence for me.* Your pattern does appear to match. https://regex101.com/r/IyFw36/1

Comment: The addition of `is not working` should *still* flag the sentence for you; it is part of a string. It depends on which language you're using and how exactly you're matching. Sharing some code showcasing this would really help.

Comment: Try: `^(Online Mobile Order|Mobile Online Order|Online Order Mobile)$`

Comment: I'm using an automation tool which is an add-on for Jira. It's called Automation for Jira :)
However, it doesn't pick that input as I explained above. I'm not sure what engine they are using to parse the input.

Answer (score 1):

This works if your engine supports conditionals.
By and large its PCRE, Perl, Boost.

`(?i:(?m:[ ]|^)(?:(?(1)(?!))(Order)|(?(2)(?!))(Mobile)|(?(3)(?!))(Online))){3}`

https://regex101.com/r/w7zfyV/1

Expanded

```
 (?i:
      (?m: [ ] | ^ )
      (?:
           (?(1)(?!))
           ( Order )                     # (1)
        |  (?(2)(?!))
           ( Mobile )                    # (2)
        |  (?(3)(?!))
           ( Online )                    # (3)
      )
 ){3}
```

Comment: I'll give it a go.
I tried using https://regex101.com/ and play with it.
So far I came up with ```/((online|mobile).*?orders?)/gi``` but I'm not sure if I'm in the right way really.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
/^.?(Online Mobile Order|Mobile Online Order|Online Order Mobile).?$/gi
```

The `.?` matches zero or more of any character before and after those word combinations. You should also use the `i` flag so it matches any character case.

Use this [online regex tester](https://regex101.com/) to test.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that. How about ```/(online|order|mobile).*?``` do you think it would work? (I ignore lower case at the moment)

Comment: Yes it will work if you place the wild card .? before and after.

Comment: you mean /.?(crash|stuck|job).*?

Comment: Yes. And you don't need the asterix. Just `.?` on either end. https://regex101.com/r/m1BYHU/1